# parse XML with invalid characters

Tags: java, xml-parsing

I have a XML file which contains some invalid characters (character not supported in XML 1.0).
I want to parse the file but I am getting exception that XML contains invalid characters.
Is there any possible way to parse the XML with invalid characters. Or skip the node attribute which contains invalid character.

Comment: Would it work if you forced the parser in XML 1.1 mode, or changed the XML prolog to declare your file as 1.1 XML (which is kind of a hack, but one of the easiest to test for) ?

Answer (score 0):

A possible workaround would be loading it in as a string and replacing the invalid character with a valid character or tag so you know it was there. Then parse normally.

Comment: Thanks for response..The size of XML is too large so it is a complex procedure for me.I have a line number where I am getting the invalid characters, so is there any way to modify content of particular line.

Answer (score 0):

So you mean there are characters &, < , > (" or ' in attributes) around? You can write your own InputStream decorator and convert those "bad" characters into escaped ones. Your InputStream takes this invalid data and returns valid data for the next processing stage:

```
InputStream yourFancyIllegalCharConverter = new YourFancyIllegalCharConverter( realInputStream );
XMLInputFactory factory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
XMLStreamReader parser = factory.createXMLStreamReader( yourFancyIllegalCharConverter );
```